# strange Hibernate-generated SQL with OVER() function and ORDER BY ORDER ON

Tags: sql, db2, window-functions

I'm having a problem with a slight ordering anomaly in a legacy web application, and figured I'd start with the back-end SQL query generated by Hibernate with DB2Dialect:

```
FROM   (SELECT inner2_.*,
           ROWNUMBER()
             OVER(
               ORDER BY ORDER OF inner2_) AS rownumber_
    FROM   (SELECT this_.sohn                       AS SOHN1_15_11_,
                   this_.aslc                       AS ASLC2_15_11_,
                   this_.cc                         AS CC3_15_11_,
                   bb1_.sbn                         AS SBN1_2_0_,
                   bb1_.abc                         AS ABC3_4_5_,
                   mh2_.smhn                        AS SMHN1_9_1_,
                   mh2_.sabc                        AS SABC3_4_6_,
                   og8_.sogn                        AS SOGN1_11_2_,
                   og8_.sogo                        AS SOGO3_4_7_,
                   oc9_.socn                        AS SOCN_1_13_3_,
                   oc9_.soco                        AS SOCO_3_4_8_
            FROM   ott.oh this_
                   INNER JOIN ott.bb1_
                           ON this_.sbn = bb1_.sbn
                   INNER JOIN ott.mh2_
                           ON this_.smhn = mh2_.smhn
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN ott.og og8_
                                ON this_.sogn = og8_.sogn
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN ott.oc oc9_
                                ON this_.socn = oc9_.socn
            WHERE  ( 1 = 1 )
                   AND bb1_.sbn = ?
                   AND mh2_.smhn = ?
            FETCH first 200 ROWS only) AS inner2_) AS inner1_
WHERE  rownumber_ > 190
ORDER  BY rownumber_
```

What does this query do? I am especially curious about `OVER()`, which isn't coming up when I google for such a SQL function (but it is an MDX function?).

This query functions in the application to grab the last page of a paginated list that is ordered by a field that doesn't even appear in the query. The query to populate the first page on initial load is different, and its generated SQL does ORDER BY the desired field.

So to get through this I need to understand how the query functions. Takers?

Comment: Are you asking about OVER() ? There is no ORDER() in the query or do you want to understand the ORDER clause - just to calrify

Comment: Sorry I need glasses. I was looking at an OVER() function. That will probably help with the googling. Thanks for triggering my brain into wakefulness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OVER() is part of so called OLAP functions - a good desrciption can be found in the DB2 SQL Cookbook - i.e. available here:

http://www.ids-system.de/images/Downloads/DB2V97CK.PDF

It is a group of really useful functions.

Also good additional stuff

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0401kuznetsov/